# Android API - disable right landscape?

Tags: android, api

I am busy writing an app that lets me use my phone (Galaxy S2 2.2.3) as a steering wheel. Just a nerdy weekend project really.

I have gotten everything working regarding calculating the orientation of the device using SensorManager.GetOrientation() with a slight snag. The rotation around the axis which comes out of the screen and back of the phone rises from 0 to 90 degrees and then falls back down in the same manner to 0 degrees instead of proceeding to 180.

This had me really confused until I read something somewhere that suggested the API might be flipping (internally as the screen doesn't flip) orientation so the phones coordinates system is flipping from left to right landscape (Its worth noting that I have it locked in landscape mode in the Manifest). This explains the weird behaviour in terms of orientation.

Does anyone know how to stop this happening, or have I gone wrong completely in my understanding?

Comment: Do you want to make your activity flipping 180 degrees?

Comment: No, I just want the sensor reading to climb to 180 instead of getting to 90, flip orientation and then fall back down to 0.